# When is the structure sheaf not coherent over itself?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

In the higher direct image sheaves section of Vakil (18.8), he makes the assumptions that $\mathscr{O}_Y$ is coherent over itself several times. How could $\mathscr{O}_Y$ not be Noetherian over itself? Over each affine open $U_i = $Spec $A_i$, isn't $\mathscr{O}_Y|_{U_i} = \widetilde{A_i}$, which is generated by 1?

Comment: Note that when the scheme is not locally Noetherian, then a coherent sheaf is not necessarily one that is locally a finitely generated O_X-module. See 13.6.1 in Vakil. 


So what you're looking here for is an example of a non-coherent ring, which Vakil also gives an example here http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/incoherent.pdf .